# jQuery partial form reset to initial value

Tags: jquery

I have a form that has a bunch of input type="text" boxes that are loaded with values from a database. I can then change these values and POST. This form has a few subsections that I have boxed in with framesets. What I would like to do is give the user a button to undo any changes they have made to inputs in a particular fameset. I know I can use:

```
$('#myForm').get(0).reset();
```

To reset the entire form. I was hoping that I could do something like:

```
$('#myForm #myFrameset').get(0).reset();
```

or

```
$('#myForm input').get(0).reset();
```

to reset the input boxes within a particular frameset. However, (valuable lesson of the day for this noob) .reset() is only a form selector so when I ('#myForm #myFrameset') I am selecting an element and not a form.

I don't want to reload from the database because it seems to me that the data I want is there. I just can't figure out how to access it without resetting the entire form. I'm going to work on a function where I store the value in the input placeholder and set the input value to the placeholder value on reset button click. It should work but I'm wondering is there a simpler way to do this in jQuery? Is there a better way to do this in general?

Comment: The data can be accessed with `$(theinput).prop("defaultValue")` you'll have to loop through them and reset them.

Comment: Thank you! Just for S&G's I ended ups using $('#myFrameset input[name="myInput"]').val($('#myFrameset input[name="myInput"]').prop("defaultValue")); I used name instead of ID becuase it saved me the passing of the ID to my function.